# Getting the value in one method to the other method

Tags: javascript, object, methods, javascript-objects

The value which is created in one method can be used in another by calling it but in my case I get an error. please advise

```
(function() {
      var s = {
        appendToFilter: function(bread, value) {
          console.log(bread); // value is 20
          console.log(value); // value is 40
          return value; // Need this value
        },
        //Append to container in order to render filters
        appendToContainer: function(container, v, state) {
            // I need the value returned in appendToFilter here
            // I tried using global variable and tried to call appendToFilter here, no luck
            // since it depends on flow of the methods is there any work around to get the value
        },  

        getToFilter: function(value) {
          var x = 20;
          var y = 40;
          s.appendToFilter(x,y);
        }
      }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just declare one Global variable out side the function. and you can access it any where.

```
var newVal;
(function() {

      var s = {
        appendToFilter: function(bread, value) {
          console.log(bread); // value is 20
          console.log(value); // value is 40
          newVal=value;
          return value; // Need this value
        },
        //Append to container in order to render filters
        appendToContainer: function(container, v, state) {
            console.log(newVal);
        },  

        getToFilter: function(value) {
          var x = 20;
          var y = 40;
          s.appendToFilter(x,y);
        }
      }

    });
```

Comment: this doesn't work since the method calling is needed

Comment: Have you tried to add new variable in "var s" and then try to use it? Some thing Like as 'var s = { newVal : null, appendToFilter : function(){}}'

Comment: Can you, return y in getToFilter and call getToFilter in appendToContainer fucntion. Like as  

`appendToContainer: function(container, v, state) {
           var obj1 = getToFilter();
           console.log(obj1);
        },  

        getToFilter: function(value) {
          var x = 20;
          var y = 40;
          s.appendToFilter(x,y);   
         return y;   
        }`

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() {
      var s = {
        appendToFilter: function(bread, value) {
          console.log(bread); 
          console.log(value);
          return value; 
        },
        //Append to container in order to render filters
        appendToContainer: function(container, v, state) {
            var value = s.appendToFilter(10, 20); // call it as you used it getToFilter function
    console.log(value)

        },  

        getToFilter: function(value) {
          var x = 20;
          var y = 40;
          s.appendToFilter(x,y);
        }
      }

    });
```

Comment: I get a value undefined, with this snippet

Comment: can you show the snippet how you are calling the above function